# Does closing Scanner affect performance

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input, performance-testing

I was solving a competitive problem and in problem, I was taking user input using scanner.
These are 2 code segments, one closing scanner and one without closing scanner.

> Closing scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JImSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        while (n-- > 0) {
            double number = (Math.log(Long.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())) / Math.log(2));
            System.out.println((int) number - number == 0 ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

> **Not** closing scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JImSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        while (n-- > 0) {
            double number = (Math.log(Long.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())) / Math.log(2));
            System.out.println((int) number - number == 0 ? "Yes" : "No");
        }           
    }
}
```

The first one (closing scanner) give me score `14.47`,
and second one (not closing scanner) gives `15.22`.
I think compiler is freeing the resource when i use `scanner.close();` and that is why there is a difference in the scores.

This is the score judge formula.

> It is assigned a score of 100.  Suppose, you submit a solution of n
>   characters, then your score is (56/n)*100.

Comment: You're absolutely correct that the jvm clears some resources when closing the Scanner. if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked as well.

Comment: How does the score relate to performance?!

Comment: Is this some sort of code golf?

Comment: yes this golf problem.

Comment: i think as there is time and memory limit so it effects performance. and memory and time is a factor of judging score

Comment: Uhm, are you aware that many code *golf* questions are about the *size of the source code*? Less is better. So, if you omit a statement, that makes the source code shorter and, hence, yields a higher score. Not related to "performance" in any way.

Comment: oh thats why code in rubby gets more than 100

Comment: thanks @HannoBinder you gave me a valid point

Comment: In a totally different context, open streams will not be closed by the JVM when it shuts down. The OS will detect those and close those (sockets / ports / streams) slowly. So, yes, not closing streams explicitly might lead to resource leak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is assigned a score of 100. Suppose, you submit a solution of n
>   characters, then your score is (56/n)*100.

You're kidding right? The score for one solution is 14.47. This means that your source code was `56 / (14.47/100) =~= 387` characters.(`=~=` for a lack of a "about equals" symbol)

In the other instance, you had a score of 15.22, which means that your source code was `56 / (15.22/100) =~= 368` characters long.

A difference of 29 characters, which is probably the length of your line of source code that says `scanner.close();` (including leading spaces, two trailing spaces and a carriage return/line feed pair)

This has nothing to do with the performance of your code.

Comment: that was a well spotted observation.

Comment: thanks @Erwin as Hanno Binder  Suggested i got the point before this i don't no about golf problem.

Comment: It's hard to win a code golf problem that scores on code length with Java. Wonder if someone has managed to write a preprocessor that allows you to write very short Java code. Haven't seen it yet though.